# Convert list containing multiple numpy arrays to single numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a list that looks as such (this is a subset):

```
[array([[1.]]), array([[0.95105652]]), array([[0.80901699]]), array([[0.58778525]]), array([[0.30901699]]), array([[-2.77555756e-14]]), array([[-0.30901699]]), array([[-0.58778525]]), array([[-0.80901699]]), array([[-0.95105652]]), array([[0.95105652]]), array([[0.9045085]]), array([[0.76942088]]), array([[0.55901699]]), array([[0.29389263]]), array([[1.70086167e-13]]), array([[-0.29389263]])
```

Essentially, each element is a single numpy array. It's dimensions are

```
np.shape(ls)
(100, 1, 1)
```

I do not quite understand where the third dimensions come from, but what I want is to extract all 100 values from this list, and place it in a numpy array of dimensions `(100,)`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just build a comprehension and convert it to a numpy array:

```
result = np.array([i[0][0] for i in ls])
```

Here are some timeit results with your example:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("""np.ravel(ls)""", globals = globals(),number=100000)
1.2485979999983101
>>> timeit.timeit("""np.transpose(ls)[0][0]""", globals = globals(),number=100000)
1.4232207000022754
>>> timeit.timeit("""np.array([i[0][0] for i in ls])""", globals = globals(),number=100000)
0.7894333000003826
```

With a list of size 100, it becomes:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("""np.ravel(ls)""", globals = globals(),number=100000)
5.593053000000509
>>> timeit.timeit("""np.transpose(ls)[0][0]""", globals = globals(),number=100000)
6.153891400001157
>>> timeit.timeit("""np.array([i[0][0] for i in ls])""", globals = globals(),number=100000)
4.391332800001692
```

Comment: Thank you! What does i[0][0] do?